# Factorial remainder

Tags: factorial

Given a number n,the problem is to find all x (1<=x<=n), such that (x-1)! ie (factorial of (x-1)) leaves a remainder of x-1 when divided by x.I have tried of a dynamic programming solution  where dp[n] gives the number of such numbers for given n,but finding the factorial doesn't seem to work for large numbers.Can we use modular arithmetic properties to solve this?

Comment: This seems like a poorly-conceived problem. When x is 1, x-1 is 0, and the problem asks us to divide by 0. When x is greater than 1, the remainder is always 0, since (x-1)! is by definition a multiple of x-1 for x>1.

Comment: Also, x is never a possible remainder when dividing anything by x-1, since the remainder is always less than the divisor.

Comment: Are you sure you've described the problem correctly?

Comment: My bad,the remainder should be x-1 when divided by x

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0):

When (x-1)! is divided by (x-1) for x > 1, the remainder will always be 0. Since it's given that the remainder is x, you need to find all x such that x is congruent to 0 modulo x-1. (Notice that x itself is congruent to 1 mod x - 1).

[image]